# jQuery toggle isn't working properly

Tags: jquery, html

If have a little problem with my jQuery.

I have to Hide and Show this

```
<td class="tdtext">
    <button class="prijzenknop">
        Prijzen 
        <div class="prijzen" style="display:none;">
            Jip's SpartelClub (één kind + één begeleider)                                               <br />
            Prijs: <b>&euro; 8,50</b>
            <br />
        </div>
    </button>
</td>
```

for what I'm using this jQuery

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".prijzenknop").each(function(){
                        $(".prijzenknop").click(function(){
                            $(this).find(".prijzen").toggle();                              
                        });
                    });
                });
```

The problem with this is that the `.toggle` function doesn't work.
If I use `.show` instead of `.toggle` It works. But then I can't toggle it of.

It's no problem that all the information will show up inside the button.

Comment: it works well check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aYjx5/

Comment: @PratikJoshi no more works if number of matched elements is even: http://jsfiddle.net/aYjx5/1/

Comment: You probably don't want the `<div>` to be *inside* the `<button>` element; I'm actually surprised that's valid HTML (or at least Firefox seems to be handling it like it is).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The button is just temporary, this won't be in the final design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prijzenknop").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".prijzen").toggle();
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you were binding it multiple times and so toggle() was called and recalled. So if number of matched elements is even, toggle() won't get any effect.

Answer (score 3):

becouse you use the .each you add the click event muliple times.
Use:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".prijzenknop").each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $(this).find(".prijzen").toggle();                              
                });
            });
        });
```

or use:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".prijzenknop").click(function(){
                  $(this).find(".prijzen").toggle();                              
              });
        });
```

becourse when you add a click event to `$(".prijzenknop")` you already add the event to all the elements with that class

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.prijzenknop').click(function() {
        $('.prijzen').toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user69152, of course in 
$(document).ready(function() :) I complete, thanks for your return.

Comment: There are multiple table on this page, so if I don't use `$(this.find` It'll toggle all the buttons on the page.

Comment: @user69152, If there are several, you're right. I Up your comment.